# if else is not working with single option select

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am struggling with my code for getting the result but I didn't see success so I want your help.I want to add class active to selected option and all other options will remove the class.

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
  li.active{color: blue;}
```

jQuery:

```
 $('li').click(function() {
    if(true) {
       $(this).addClass('active');
    }else{
       $('li').removeClass('active');
    };
 });
```

Comment: `if (true) {..}` will always be `true`... you aren't checking for anything. Besides, you really don't even need to check anything. Just remove the class from all `.active` elements, and then add the class to the current element.

Comment: you don't need if else block even just add / remove your class to all li and then add specific class using `this`.

Comment: click event means it will be always true inside the event.. so just remove that if else or you can use toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did if(true), it will be always executed
so use this

```
    $('li').click(function() {
           //remove all active class of all li
            $('li').removeClass('active');  
            //set active class for this li only
              $(this).addClass('active');
      }
```

});

I created this [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t780so54/)! for you

Answer (score 0):

try this code :-

```
<ul class="nav-list">
<li class="active">One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
```

```
$('.nav-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
$('.nav-list li.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');});
```